# How to get window (like dialog, popupmenu...)

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm working on library and it should find out if non-activity window (e.g. dialog, popupmenu....) is on the screen. I tried this...

```
((Activity)context).getWindow()
```

but it always return main activity window, not what I want.

Is there any way to get Window on the screen or activated?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is getting the window of the activity because you are calling the `getWindow()` method on your activity object.

Instead `((Activity)context).getWindow()` try `dialog.getWindow()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use instanceof to check if context is Activity and then call context.getWindow()

```
if(context instanceof Activity)
{
  Window window = ((Activity)context).getWindow();
}
```

Note: Activity and Dialog share same window so calling getWindow on dialog will return same object.

Answer (score -1):

You must specify activity you want instead of (Activity).

Like this;

```
((Activity)context).getWindow()
```

to

```
((YouWantActivity)context).getWindow()
```

maybe 'context' can be change (to: 'this ' or stg.)